# How to query cms content using Content Slug

Tags: lightning-web-components, content-builder, salesforce-cms

I am trying to create a lwc which can take content-slug as a parameter and displays the content on experience cloud. I found this class which has many apis but couldn't find one that takes the content-slug and returns the content.
Below is a method which returns content based on contentId selected in builder using ContentReference property in meta.xml.

Is there any way to use content-slug to get CMS content? Please help.

```
   public static Map<String, ConnectApi.ManagedContentNodeValue> getContent(
       String contentId,
       Integer page,
       Integer pageSize,
       String language,
       String filterby
   ) {
       try {
           String networkId = Network.getNetworkId();
           System.debug('>>>> contentId' + contentId);
           ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersionCollection contentCollection = ConnectApi.ManagedContent.getManagedContentByContentKeys(
               networkId,
               new List<String>{ contentId },
               0,
               1,
               language,
               filterby,
               false
           );
           return contentCollection.items[0].contentNodes;
       } catch (ConnectApi.ConnectApiException e) {
           System.debug('Error Message : ' + e);
           Map<String, ConnectApi.ManagedContentNodeValue> mcnvMap = new Map<String, ConnectApi.ManagedContentNodeValue>();
           return mcnvMap;
       }
   }

meta.xml for lwc

<property
type="ContentReference"
name="contentId"
label="Content ID"
filter="news"
/>
```